# ADB does not detect my device while in Recovery Mode

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G (Falcon-xt 1033).

Recently I successfully flashed cm 13 nighly on my device, everything worked fine, used the phone a little while, then flashed supersu and device went into a boot loop.

I had removed rom zip files from device storage, so I am trying to push rom zip into my device via adb. But the adb does not detect my device(nor does my laptop- running ubuntu 14.04). I tried a bunch of things from from trying all ports to updating adb version to creating 51-android.rules file under etc/udev/rules.d/
The recovery my device used is cwm.

I want to access the storage drive of my device either by adb or by any alternative to push the rom .zip and other files. How exactly can I go about solving this problem.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: What recovery application do you use? For instance, with TWRP, you could simply boot into recovery, enable MTP, then simple load up your internal storage (or external sdcard), copy whatever you want copied, then flash. I will recommend you wipe-wipe-totally-clean-everything before re-installing. If supersu continues to give problems, perhaps its unstable with your phone/CM yet.

Comment: Thanks @Rexford you solved a major problem. For some strange reason MTP was not enabled and cwm lacked options. Flashed TWRP onto my device, enabled the MTP and finally moved using the gui way(avoided the adb situation). After all the flashed phone working perfectly(even the adb shows my device now). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're using CWM (which isn't developed in a fast pace), you could switch to using TWRP, boot into recovery, enable MTP, and simply mount your internal storage or external sd card.

Copy whatever files you want onto whichever location of your choice. Unmount and flash. As I mentioned earlier, I will recommend you *wipe-wipe-totally-clean-everything* before re-installing. You don't want any traces of anything lingering around to hunt you!

Considering the above step worked for you, this point might not be helpful in your case, but to someone. If after everything above, supersu continues to give problems, perhaps its unstable with your phone/CM yet, and you might want to either get an updated version, or find a similar app that's stable with your ROM.